# Windows Server 2008 - Prevent Error Recovery screen on next boot

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2

I would like to be able to revert to a snapshot taken from a running Windows Server 2008 VM, and boot it up without seeing the Windows Error Recovery screen (Windows did not shut down successfully, choose between Safe Mode and Start Windows Normally).

In Windows Server 2003 it is possible to prevent the Windows Error Recovery screen  by deleting the value `LastAliveStamp` in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Reliability`

Although this key does still exist in Windows Server 2008, deleting it does not have the same effect.

The accepted answer for [this forum post](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winservergen/thread/41be7130-d952-456b-a596-57e12d8482f4/) indicates that the presence of the following items on a boot indicate that the previous shutdown was abnormal:

- The `LastAliveStamp` registry value from above
- The files `lastalive0.dat` and `lastalive1.dat` in `C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\LocalService\AppData\Local`

My approach so far has been to remove all of the above before taking the snapshot so that on the next boot it looks like Windows was shut down correctly.

I have tried deleting the files and the registry key before taking the snapshot, but when I revert to the snapshot and power on the VM I still see the Error Recovery screen.

I have been trying this with both Windows Server 2008 and Windows Server 2008 R2, if they each require a different solution for this I am interested in knowing them both.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I might accomplish this, or other things I can try?

Comment: Try also to start MSCONFIG.EXE, go to tab BOOT and remove Safe Mode if it's checked.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**bcdedit** works for this on win 7 ultimate (*must be run with UAC off or in a cmd prompt with administrative priv's*):

```
bcdedit /set {current} bootstatuspolicy ignoreallfailures
```

To restore original settings:

```
bcdedit /set {default} bootstatuspolicy displayallfailures
```

**Description:**

Boot Configuration Data (BCD) files provide a store that is used to describe boot applications and boot application settings. The objects and elements in the store effectively replace Boot.ini.

BCDEdit is a command-line tool for managing BCD stores. It can be used for a variety of purposes, including creating new stores, modifying existing stores, adding boot menu options, and so on.

**Sources & Further reading:**

- Reference Sheet (most thorough reference @ 29 pages): [BCDEDIT Reference (.doc)](http://iainlbc.com/BCDedit_reff.doc)
- BCD FAQ: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721886(WS.10).aspx#BKMK_bcdedit
- BCDEdit Command-Line Options (not as good as the .doc reference above): http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc709667(WS.10).aspx

EDIT: Confirmed this tool is compatible with Server 2008 [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721886%28WS.10%29.aspx)

Comment: This is great, just tested with Server 2008 and I'm getting the behavior I want.  I am still interested in figuring out a method to make it not look like an error using registry changes (rather than just ignore the error), if there are no answers with that information this will be accepted and get the bounty.  Thanks!

Comment: [I mentioned the same thing](http://superuser.com/questions/145600/how-does-one-skip-windows-did-not-shut-down-successfully-in-win7-64/255055#255055) over on SuperUser last month.

Comment: Glad I could help. I can't find any reference as to what registry values are changed or could be deleted to achieve the same affect. You might try exporting the registry before and after forcing a crash and doing a diff of the two exports to determine what values changed and playing with the results. Here's a working diff port for windows: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/diffutils.htm

Comment: Awesome.  I can confirm that, as hoped and expected, this works with Windows 2008 Server R2.

Answer (score 0):

When you take a snapshot of a running VM you'll have a crash-consistent snapshot.

All of this can be avoided by shutting the VM down normally, then taking your snapshot when it's already off. Then each fresh boot is a full, clean boot.